# How to access JSON API from a link in another API

Tags: json, angular, typescript, get, httprequest

I have an API from which I need to access the **href** attribute of **data** that directs me to another API to get the data I need.
I don't know how to access that API for each ID I receive.

JSON 1

```
{
    "jsonapi": {
      "version": "1.0",
      "meta": {
        "links": { "self": { "href": "http://jsonapi.org/format/1.0/" } }
      }
    },
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "0958d35rs13",
        "links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "https://0958d35rs13"
          }
        },
        "attributes": {
          "img_array": [
            "https://testPerson1.jpg",
            "https://testPerson1.pdf"
          ],
          "num_ref": 1
        }
      }
    ]
    }
```

JSON 2 (is the link that I get from the first JSON)

````
{
    "jsonapi": {
      "version": "1.0",
      "meta": {
        "links": { "self": { "href": "http://jsonapi.org/format/1.0/" } }
      }
    },
    "data": {
      "id": "0958d35rs13",
      "links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "https://0958d35rs13"
        }
      },
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Pepe",
        "secondName": "James"
      }
    }
}
```

INTERFACE:
````

export interface Person {
id: string,
image: string,
links: {
self: {
href: string
}
}
}

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Person } from '../interface/inmueble';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  url = "https://apipersons/

  getAllUsers(): Observable<Inmueble[]>{
    return this.http.get<Inmueble[]>(this.url);
  }
```

PEOPLE TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../services/api.service';
import { Person } from '../interface/inmueble';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-people',
  templateUrl: './people.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./people.component.scss']
})
export class PeopleComponent implements OnInit {

  person: Person[] = [];

  constructor( public apiService: ApiService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void{
    
    this.apiService.getAllUsers()
      .subscribe( (res: any) => {
        this.person = res.data
    } )
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. JSON is by nature a JS object so, why not just accessing the property ? Like `value.data[0].links.self.href` ? Can you specify where you are stuck ?

Comment: "https://testPerson1.jpg", isnt an url it looks like a local url  or just a filename with https stuck on the front, take the name part and add the api url onto the front of it

Comment: I don't know how to do a get through the link of the first API.
That is to say, in my first API I get the link of a person and that link takes me to another different API with their data.
I don't know how to get this data.